# listbox with 2 different Datatemplates

Tags: c#, wpf

need to view 2 different controls that i need to add to my listbox.
The controls are of type IControl

so i did the following:

Controls.cs

```
interface IControl
{
    double X { get; set; }
    double Y { get; set; }
}

class MyButton : Button, IControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyButton(string buttonText, double x, double y)
    {
        this.Content = buttonText;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    public MyButton()
    {
    }

    public double X
    {
        get
        { return x;}
        set
        {
           x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return y;}
        set
        {
            y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }

  }

class MyLabel : Label, IControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyLabel(int number, double x, double y)
    {
        this.Content = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    public MyLabel()
    {
    }

    public double X
    {
        get{ return x;}
        set
        {
            x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }
    public double Y
    {
        get{ return y;}
        set
        {
            y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }

  }
```

now in ViewModel.cs i have

```
class ViewModel 
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<IControl> controls = new ObservableCollection<IControl>();
    public ViewModel()
    {
        var m1 = new MyButton("Test String inside button",0,0);
        var m2 = new MyLabel(1123, 0, 80);
        controls.Add(m1);
        controls.Add(m2);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IControl> Controls
    {
        get {return controls;}
    }
}
```

and in my mainWindow.xaml

```
    <ListBox
        x:Name="listBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        >
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyButton}">
                <Button Content="{Binding}"
                MouseDown="button_MouseDown"
                PreviewMouseUp="button_MouseUp"
                PreviewMouseMove="button_MouseMove"
                />
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="labelTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyLabel}">
                <Label Content="{Binding}" Background="Aqua"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style
                TargetType="ListBoxItem"
                >
                <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding X}"
                    />
                <Setter
                    Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Y}"
                    />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

The listbox is showing the MyButton and the MyLabel i added to the observableCollection, but the datatemplates are doing nothing.
The Events in the buttonTemplate are not firing, and the background of the label is not set.

What is wrong ?
any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `MyButton` inherited from `System.Windows.Controls.Button`, and `MyLabel` - from `System.Windows.Controls.Label`?

Comment: Yes both MyLabel and MyButton does...i didnt find another way to add them to one observablecollection if i didnt find a common type between them ..

Answer (score 0):

The first problem.
It is a bad idea, in general, to inherit View Model layer types from `Visual` and its descendants (like `Control`). Define view models in view model layer:

```
// former IControl, renamed to avoid confusing with view layer
public interface ICanvasItem
{
    object Content { get; set; }
    double X { get; set; }
    double Y { get; set; }
}

public class MyButton : ICanvasItem, INotifyPropertyChanged { /* ... */}
public class MyLabel : ICanvasItem, INotifyPropertyChanged { /* ... */}
```

The second problem. Template lookup for the items control can be performed in three ways:

- using `ItemTemplate` property. This is not an option, since you need two different templates;
- using `DataTemplateSelector` via `ItemTemplateSelector` property;
- using default templates per type, declared somewhere in resource dictionaries.

You're almost going the third way, *but*, you templates has a key, and this doesn't allow templates to be applied by default. To fix this, just throw away `x:Key` attributes, and let the type be the template key:

```
   <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyButton}">
            <Button Content="{Binding Content}"
            MouseDown="button_MouseDown"
            PreviewMouseUp="button_MouseUp"
            PreviewMouseMove="button_MouseMove"
            />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyLabel}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Content}" Background="Aqua"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
```

More about data templating could be read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: THANK YOU... it works now... just removing the x:key did the trick.. and iam not inheriting from Button and Label now...thanks again ...sorry i cant upvote you, but this is to say that this solution DOES WORK...thanks again

Answer (score -1):

You are binding to a collection of IControl, therefore anything you add into this collection will be treated as an IControl, not it's respected class (MyButton or MyLabel)

Therefore on the interface, the types of these items in the list are IControl, not MyButton or MyLabel, therefore the style is not applied.

Perhaps you need to rethink your UI design?

Comment: When applying data template to an item, controls consider run-time type of item.

Comment: mmm, i dont know who gave you the -1...
But i will think about your suggestion, thank you...

Ahh.. its true Dennis, it will have the runtime type...

Comment: I don't think this is the case, certainly for collections. If they were to change their ObservableCollection to <MyLabel> and comment out adding the button, then the style should be applied to the label.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MikeEason: yes, you are. When some control has to render its content and apply template, template lookup is performed using content's run-time type (result of `Object.GetType` method).